# git-p4 vs git-svn

Tags: svn, git, perforce

My company currently uses SVN for it's repository.  In order to get better merging and local branches/revisions I've been using git-svn over a subset of the larger repository.  My company was recently purchased and one of the services offered by the corporate mothership is centralized SVN or Perforce hosting.

Given that neither Perforce or SVN offer the complete feature set I require I'm most likely going to continue to use git as the front end to whichever we choose.  Is the user experience for git-p4 better than git-svn?  Does git-p4 have suffient user base so that the client is up to date and bugs are fixed quickly?

This is a big repository, 100,000+ revisions which a very high branching factor and a non-standard layout. Does git-p4 suck less than git-svn for repositories of this scale?  For example an initial fetch of the full SVN repository using git-svn has been running for over a month and it's only up to revision 60,000.  Does this get any better when using Perforce as the back end?

And yes, going full native git is a possibility, but not a very likely one.

Answer (score 0):

Choose `git-svn`, so you don't have to deal with those perforce branching craziness.

Comment: What "branching craziness" are you referring to?  In my experience, Perforce's branching mechanism has proved very reliable.

Comment: Doesn't both Perforce and Subversion use similar branching techniques? Personally, I'd use git-svn because it's much more widely used. About 5 years ago, most corporations refused to use Subversion because it was "open source". Instead, they moved from things like ClearCase to Perforce. Now, these same companies see great advantages in using open source software (wide usage, so it's easy to find talent. No license hell or renewal. Cheaper. Usually better supported, etc.) Very likely, this company uses Perforce because that's what they bought five years ago. Now they're using SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor)? It is able to convert both from SVN and Perforce.